# Git Checkout errors

Tags: git, github, cygwin, commit, git-checkout

I am using a script to automatically checkout the first commit of each month, for the last 12 months.  Occasionally something strange happens and I am no longer allowed to checkout past commits.  The error goes something like this:

`error: Your local changes to the following files wold be overwritten by checkout:`

`db tests/framework.cpp`

`Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.  Aborting`

This has happened many times (I am not editing any files, just checking them out). I usually just download a fresh copy of the repo from Github and start the process again and it works.  But once it breaks I don't know how to fix it, and it keeps happening.  Any thoughts?

Here is the iteration going on in my script, followed by the output of `git status`

```
for i in {12..1}

do

cd
cd git/mongodb/mongo

git checkout master                   
git checkout $(git rev-list --before "$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -$i months 00:01" +%Y-%m)-01" -n 1 HEAD)
git checkout master
```

Git status:

On branch master

Changes not staged for commit:

```
        modified:    dbtests/framework.cpp
```

Untracked files:

```
       SHA1.txt
       SHA1.txt.
       file
       file.
```

no changes added to commit

Comment: Can we see the code from that part of the script?

Comment: What is the output of `git status` when that occurs?

Comment: What's your configuration setting for core.autocrlf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--force` flag to make Git do the checkout anyway.

Alternatively, you could use `git reset --hard` instead to reset to the commits, rather than using checkout.

Comment: Thanks Amber. Are there any downsides to using `--force` and `git reset --hard`     ?  And if I use `git reset --hard`, will `git checkout master` return me to the master?

Comment: `--force` was not recognized, but `git reset --hard` works.  But I'm not sure how to return to the most current commit afterwards.  Help?

Comment: Using `git reset --hard` moves the branch pointer around if you're currently on a branch. If you don't want to modify the current branch, either check out a new one or use `git checkout -f`. If you already moved your pointer around, you can use the remote tracking ref (assuming it's up-to-date): `git reset --hard origin/master`. Failing that, you can use the reflog (`git reflog`) to find where your branch used to be pointing and reset to that.

Comment: Great, I've got it.  Thank you for this very useful help.

Answer (score 0):

The 2019+ syntax would now be using the [new `git switch` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) (Git 2.23+)

```
git switch -f ...
```

The -f is an alias for the `--discard-changes` option:

> Proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD.
>   Both the index and working tree are restored to match the switching target.
>   If `--recurse-submodules` is specified, submodule content is also restored to match the switching target.
>
> This is used to throw away local changes.